# How to create server on azure and host php,mysql site on that

Tags: php, mysql, azure, wiki

I wanted to host PHP site on azure and following steps same as described here:

**Create a PHP-MySQL web app in Azure App Service and deploy using Git
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/**

But, here I am not getting any **Web app + MySQL** under Web Apps option.
May be I am missing any steps to enable php ?

So please can anybody guides me ?

**---------------- Updated ------------- Step : 2 --------------**

Thanks a lot to https://stackoverflow.com/users/793891/csharprocks to guide me how to create php subscription.
But Now I am stuck that what to do next from here.

I have used same link but I think its to old link as I am not getting such steps.

because **what I followed**

(1)Login to the Azure Portal.

(2)Click the Marketplace.

(3)Click Web + Mobile, then Free trial(signup here).

(4) Got subscription confirmation mail from Microsoft,

but what to do next from here ?

Answer (score 3):

The **Web App + MySQL** option is found in the marketplace.  In the preview portal, click on the **New** button, select **Marketplace**, then **Web + Mobile**.  You'll see a list of options, one being **Web App + MySQL**.

[image: Azure Preview Portal]

Comment: I have created (subscription) with free trial option but what to do after that ? please can you guide me on that ?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: Create a PHP-MySQL web app in Azure App Service and deploy using Git https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/

Comment: I have used same link but I think its to old link as I am not getting such steps, because what I followed (1)Login to the Azure Portal.(2)Click the Marketplace.(3)Click Web + Mobile, then Free trial(signup here).(4) Got subscription confirmation mail from microsoft, but what to do next from here ?

Answer (score 1):

You also can create a Web App + MySQL in [old manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com).
Click “**NEW**”=>”**COMPUTE**”=>”**WEB APP**”=>”**CUSTOM CREATE**” at the bottom navigation of the portal page to create a custom web app, we can create a MySQL database during the configuration.
[image]

Fill in the properties and at the **DATABSE** selection we select “**create a new MySQL database**”, then name it.
[image]

As Azure MySQL is provided by ClearDB, so mark the checkbox to agree the request.
[image]

Then you will succeed to create a Web app +MySQL service.