# Developing PHP-MySQL application on Azure

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I am new in Azure. I want to develop a web application on Azure. i am a bit confused about one issue. Should i develop the application locally and then deploy it to Azure ? or should I develop the app directly on Azure ? Could anyone please guide me on this issue ?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. What do you mean by developing the app directly on Azure? If you mean spinning up a VM with your dev tools and working through ssh/RDP, well that's entirely up to you.

Comment: which one is better option ? i am developing the app from scratch. what are the usual steps for developing cloud application ? i mean is it cost effective to spin up virtual machine and work on it ? or should i develop it locally first then move to it ?

Comment: There is no "better" option. How you develop is up to you, and is a matter of opinion (which is off-topic here). There's plenty of getting-started guidance on azure.com - just start looking through the docs and the dev examples for php. Then post specific questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Makogon said, you can either develop applications on local then deploy it to Azure, or you can directly develop your applications on Azure. They are all workable on Azure, that depends on you.

Generally, you need to create services on Azure, i.e. Web Apps to host PHP applications and ClearDB (MySQL services on Azure) to store your MySQL data. To create the PHP + MySQL sites services on Azure, you can see steps on [How to create server on azure and host php,mysql site on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500493/how-to-create-server-on-azure-and-host-php-mysql-site-on-that) on stack overflow.

If you have an application on local, you can deploy to Azure via GIT or FTP. You can refer to [Create a PHP-MySQL web app in Azure App Service and deploy using Git](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/) and [Create a PHP-MySQL web app in Azure App Service and deploy using FTP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/) on official site for deploying your local application on Azure Web Apps.

Also you can leverage [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) directly remoting to applications on Web Apps and develop your applications.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If i develop my application directly on Azure, what should i do with encryption software for my application ? Does Azure provide encryption software ? or i have to configure the encryption for my app ? thanks again.

Comment: WebMatrix is not available for mac :(

Comment: What do you mean encryption software? For enciphering your code? Is that you are concerning the security of your code on Azure?

Comment: yes, you are right. to encipher the code. does azure provide any mechanism for that ?

Comment: what do you mean ? if azure does not provide any security mechanism, then why should we not be concerned ?

Comment: Azure Web Apps store the source code on Azure Storage. And about the security of Azure Storage, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/#access-to-blob-table-queue-and-file-resources